# Multiplication and addition using assembly

Tags: assembly, expression, x86-16

So I am trying to calculate `Salary + (Revenue * Commission)` using the ft function however I don't get the desired output. It's also required that I use `ax`, `bx` & `cx` registers.

```
ft:  
            
      mov ax, s
      mov bx, r
      add ax, bx
      mov cx, c
      mul cx
      mov cx, ax
      ret
      
main:       
      call ft      
              
             
end:     
       call print_dec
    
    jmp .                # Stop the program from executing further
    
    
s: .word 2310     
r: .word 442      
c: .word 9
```

Comment: You’re computing (salary + reve) x comm.

Comment: How is the result supposed to be passed to print_dec? Is it in a register? What register?

Comment: What result do you expect, and what result do you get? (This should have been my first comment.)

Comment: Am expecting to get 5520 as an output

Comment: 2310 + (442 x 9) is 6288. How do you get 5520?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the brackets in the expression `Salary + (Revenue * Commission)`, you need to calculate first the part `(Revenue * Commission)`. **Even without the brackets would you have to calculate that part first since multiplication has priority over addition!**

This is the short version:

```
mov ax, r
mul c        ; DX:AX = r * c
add ax, s
ret
```

A longer version if you really have to use `AX`, `BX`, and `CX`:

```
mov ax, r
mov bx, c
mov cx, s
mul bx       ; DX:AX = r * c
add ax, cx
ret
```

What the task doesn't mention is the register `DX`. The above `mul` instruction will also change that register! If that can not be allowed you could perhaps use the 2-operands variant of the `imul` instruction (but not on [8086](/questions/tagged/8086)):

```
mov ax, r
imul ax, c   ; AX = r * c
add ax, s
ret
```

And if that particular variant of the `imul` instruction is hands-off to you, then you could multiply through a series of additions:

```
  mov cx, c
  xor ax, ax
more:
  add ax, r
  dec cx
  jnz more
  add ax, s
  ret
```

**FOLLOW-UP**

For an expression like the one you posted in a comment, `(Salary * Hrs) + (Revenue * Commission)`, you would have to store the result of the 1st multiplication in a spare register, do the 2nd multiplication, and then add both results:

```
mov ax, r
mul c        ; DX:AX = r * c
mov bx, ax

mov ax, s
mul h        ; DX:AX = s * h

add ax, bx   ; AX = (s * h) + (r * c)
ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if I had a case where I would need to calculate (Salary* hrs) + (Revenue * Commission) and I have to use yet the dx register as well.

Comment: @Fadii See my edited answer for your follow-up question.